# Unable to catch the random number generated in main method?

Tags: java

I am running this code, but I am unable to access the class variables (pg and dg) in the main method. The output I am getting is

> Dealer is starting the game
>   He has guessed a number from 0 to 9
>   Now it is your time to guess
>   Player is guessing
>   The number player 1 guessed is 0
>   Player is guessing
>   The number player 2 guessed is 0
>   Player is guessing
>   The number player 3 guessed is 0
>   The dealer guess was 0
>   All have guessed correctly

I am unable to catch the random number generated in the method.

```
class player
{
    public int pg = 0;
    public void pguess()
    {
        System.out.println("Player is guessing");
        int pg = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }
} 

class dealer
{
    public  int dg = 0;
    public void guess()
    {
        System.out.println("Dealer is starting the game");
        System.out.println("He has guessed a number from 0 to 9");
        System.out.println("Now it is your time to guess");
        int dg = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }

    public void dealerdisplay()
    {
        System.out.println("The dealer guess was " + dg);
    }
}

public class gameOn
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        dealer d = new dealer();
        player a = new player();
        player b = new player();
        player c = new player();

        d.guess();

        a.pguess();
        System.out.println("The number player 1 guessed is " + a.pg); 

        b.pguess();
        System.out.println("The number player 2 guessed is " + b.pg); 

        c.pguess();
        System.out.println("The number player 3 guessed is " + c.pg); 

        d.dealerdisplay();

        if ((d.dg == a.pg) && (d.dg == b.pg) && (d.dg == c.pg))
            System.out.println("All have guessed correctly");

        else if ((d.dg == a.pg) && (d.dg == b.pg) || (d.dg == a.pg) &&
                        (d.dg == c.pg) || (d.dg == b.pg) && (d.dg == c.pg))
            System.out.println("Two have have guessed correctly");

        else if ((d.dg == a.pg) || (d.dg == b.pg) || (d.dg == c.pg)) 
            System.out.println("One has guessed correctly");

        else
            System.out.println("No one has guessed correctly");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int pg = (int)(Math.random()*10);` should be `pg = (int)(Math.random()*10);`. By declaring a type you are actually creating a local variable that shadows the class instance variable `pg`. You assign a random number to the local variable instead of player instance variable `pg`.

Comment: Why do you declare class variables as public, instead of obeying the principles of encapsulation and create the according getter /setter?

Answer (score 5):

Here's your problem:

```
    System.out.println("Player is guessing");
    int pg = (int)(Math.random()*10);
}
```

You're declaring a new local int pg instead of setting the class member. Change to:

```
    System.out.println("Player is guessing");
    pg = (int)(Math.random()*10);
}
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Or better yet, always qualify field access with `this.`. Turn on that warning in your IDE (e.g. Eclipse), and you'll never make mistakes like that again, because the lack of `this.` makes it obvious. --- Also turn on the warning about field hiding. That would have caught it too.

Answer (score 0):

Both the variables dg and pg are getting created locally inside your guess().
By default java assigns value zero to an int type and hence every time your print its value, you are getting it as zero.

You need to simply remove int in the assignment statement inside the guess method.

```
 System.out.println("Player is guessing");
 pg = (int)(Math.random()*10);


 System.out.println("He has guessed a number from 0 to 9");
 System.out.println("Now it is your time to guess");
 dg = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```